# Can I use metadata to verify if a Primary Key and a Foreign Key values are valid?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014

I'm learning SQL and I'm doing some exercises, and I built a procedure that receives as parameters, values that will be inserted into a specific table, once the procedure is executed.

But I need to do some validations. One of the validations is to check if some values are null, because some columns don't accept null values:

```
IF(@userID IS NULL AND @userPW IS NULL)
```

I had to remove the identity property from my insert:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [TABLE] OFF
```

But now, I need to validate the primary and foreign key parameters.

I was thinking about verifying all rows from the specified table, to check if the value received by parameter is different than any other inserted primary key value.

I would use the same logic for the foreign keys, because I need to check if foreign key received by parameter, is equal to some ID from the referenced table.

But I recently met metadata, which has a lot of functionalities, and I would like to know if I can simplify the validation queries by using metadata.

Thank you.

Comment: You can use [System Information Schema Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: Thank you. I found KEY_COLUMN_USAGE

Comment: Why program that kind of validation on your own? This is what *constrainsts* are made for. A *primary key constraint* automatically checks for uniqueness and a *foreign key constraint* automatically checks if the inserted value maps to a value in the referenced column. The `IDENTITY_INSERT` setting should usually be **off** unless you need to insert values into an `IDENTITY` column (then you would temporarily turn it ON and OFF again when done).